# CodeIgniter keep showing "Whoops" page instead of error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter project, in which I want to be able to see the error messages.
I already have set `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development` in `.env` file

But still, instead of error message I see the "Whoops..." message.

My code is very simple:

Inside controller -

```
public function addRecipeF($nazev)
    {
        echo $nazev;
    }
```

Inside view, which sends data from Form to controller -

```
<form class="input-form" action="addRecipeF" method="post">

        <section class="input-label">
            <label for="nazev-input">Název receptu</label>
            <input type="text" id="nazev-input" name="nazev" />
        </section>
        <input type="submit" value="Přidat!">
    </form>
```

My .htaccess file -

```
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On


    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I also tried to set some env. variables in the main index.php file -

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
define('CI_ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

And when I print out any of those two variables in any of the views, it returns "development"...

Any idea ?

**Edit:**

Not very efficient solution, but it worked...
I replaced contents of `Views/errors/html/production.php` by `Views/errors/html/error_exception.php`

Comment: check if you are not overriding this setting in your `my_project/public/.htaccess` ?

Comment: Added the content of .htaccess

Comment: As a check you can observe the value of CI_ENVIRONMENT by placing this in your view, for instance... <?= CI_ENVIRONMENT;?>

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I could not directly print out "CI_ENVIRONMENT" because php was not able to find it... So I print out just "ENVIRONMENT" and that returned development..

Comment: Please share your `.env` file contents.